# Tailwind increase height upwards on hover

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have built the following interface using only the utility classes available in Tailwind css. When a down icon is hovered, the following menu correctly expands downwards:

[image]

My problem is with the up icon. When it is hovered, it also expands downward - I would like for it to expand *upward* but am struggling to figure out how to do so. Here is my current implementation (syntax is React/JSX):

```
<div className="flex flex-col w-auto h-6 text-xl transition duration-300 transform transition-height hover:h-40 overflow-hidden ease-out">
  {colors.reverse().map((color) => (
    <div
      className={`text-${color}-400 w-6 h-6 rounded-full transform hover:cursor-pointer hover:bg-${color}-200 text-center`}
    >
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={icon} />
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

In addition to expanding upwards, I would also like for it to **not** push the preceding div/content further up, but instead to "overlay" its contents.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use [scale](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/scale) for this.

Try with these classes `transform hover:scale-125`